# Azure Manage Instance Student Cost

Tags: azure, azure-sql-managed-instance

I am preparing for certifications and can't afford the $700+ cost for a low tier Azure managed instance. I do have pay as you go and student subscriptions but the cost is unaffordable. Is there a workaround for the pricing?

Comment: I would recommend to spin it up and then close it, Usually if you use for few days, it should not cost more than $100.

Answer (score 2):

If it is only for certification purposes the Managed Instance could (and should) be short-lived. That would bring down costs drastically. The price per hour is € 0,91 or $ 1.07.

More information: [Azure SQL Managed Instance pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/azure-sql/sql-managed-instance/single/)